# Calculate area from inputs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, height, getelementbyid, calculator, area

I've got a very simple javascript calculator here but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm sure it's something very simple to solve but just can't see it. I've spent a while on it and thought I'd be better off asking here. Any suggestions? Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/z98gb/7/

```
Width <input type="Text" name="width" size="4">  
Height <input type="Text" name="height" size="4" onkeyup=""> <br><br>
Area <input type="Text" name="area" id="area" size="4"> <br><br>
<input type="button" name="calculate" id="area" size="4" onclick="calculateArea()"    value="calculate">
```

And here's the javascript:

```
function calculateArea() {
var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
var area = width * height;
document.getElementById("area").value = area;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify an id for your input

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/z98gb/8/

Comment: Aha! That's just what I needed. Can't believe I didn't spot that. Thanks.

Comment: Also the button has the same id as the result field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your DOM values to actual numbers before performing calculations on them.  Use `parseInt` if you're working with whole numbers, or, more likely, use `parseFloat` to support decimals.

If you use `parseInt`, don't forget to specify a 10 to signify base 10.  Failure to do so will cause JavaScript to treat leading zeroes as though they were in base 8.

```
var width = parseInt(document.getElementById("width").value, 10);
var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value, 10);
var area = width * height;
```

**EDIT**

Also, as Francis notes, you forgot to add IDs to your inputs.

Comment: multiplication will take care of the type conversion. If the poster would have used addition, this would have been a problem.

Comment: The input strings will be converted automatically if used with a mathematical operator (except for + which doubles as the string concatenation operator), so that's not stopping the simple example from working with valid input. Still,  valid input isn't guaranteed so the strings definitely should be converted to numbers before use (or otherwise validated with regex or something) so that a meaningful error message can be displayed- I'd recommend the unary + operator rather than parseInt() but the main thing is that it gets done.

Comment: @nnnn - thanks for the feedback.  I'm not an avid JS programmer, but I do like the unary + operator more, come to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using getElementById and not getElementByName.  You either need to specify an id or switch what you use in your code.